# iOS CallKit reportNewIncomingCall does not display phone UI but opens app

Tags: ios, callkit

When the previous call hasn't been terminated cleanly (crash of the application for example), calling reportNewIncomingCall doesn't display the phone UI ; but the ring is triggered and the app opens.

Encountered with the latest iOS 11

Has anyone else identified this behavior? Any solution?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This strange behavior happens when the UUID of the call is the same as that of the previous call that failed.

What was the case during the tests ...